# Missing dot in Circuitikz

Tags: circuitikz

I have tried to draw a circuit with the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\tikzset{component/.style={draw,thick,circle,fill=white,minimum size =0.75cm,inner sep=0pt}}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0) to[lamp] (2,0) to (3,0) node[component]{\SI{1}{\ampere}} to (4,0) to (4,2) node[component]{?} to (4,3) to[battery1] (0,3) to (0,0);
\draw (0,1) to[lamp,*-] (2,1) to (3,1) node[component]{\SI{2}{\ampere}} to[,-*] (4,1);
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, only one dot appears in the circuit to indicate a junction as shown below:

[image]

How do I include the missing dot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To obtain what you need you can just add `short` (short circuit) key with `-*`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\tikzset{component/.style={draw,thick,circle,fill=white,minimum size =0.75cm,inner sep=0pt}}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0) to[lamp] (2,0) to (3,0) node[component]{\SI{1}{\ampere}} to (4,0) to (4,2) node[component]{?} to (4,3) to[battery1] (0,3) to (0,0);
\draw (0,1) to[lamp,*-] (2,1) to  (3,1) node[component]{\SI{2}{\ampere}} to [short,-*] (4,1);
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]